# Drupal 7: Access Denied localhost/user/[user_id] after successful login

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, cookies, drupal

I am in the process of attempting to move a localhost to however after a successful login I get "Access Denied", you are not authorized to access this page and the url is `http://mysite.dd:8083/user/[user_id]`. It doesn't appear I had successfully logged in because I see the login at the top, and I know it's not a wrong password because I have tried wrong password and have gotten back "Incorrect Password" responses that redirect me back to the login page.

I cleared the cache, disabled the securepages module, fixed the base url, have clean URLs enabled. I am working with Acquia Dev Desktop and I literally imported the database, changed the username to match that in phpmyadmin, ftp the files to the appropriate directory and imported. I have the cookie domain as follows and I don't know maybe I need to modify this?

```
 $cookie_domain = '.mysite.dd:8083';
```

I don't know if this is an issue with cookies, the database, .htaccess file, or even if there is a module preventing me from doing this. I tried the default .htaccess file and got the same result. Any thoughts and help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This question just helped me to fix a problem with a D7 site I'm maintaining. I don't really know Drupal yet, but it pointed me in the direction of the `$cookie-domain` variable - which had a default setting, not the correct site setting. Useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I switched the cookie domain from `".mysite.dd:8083"` to `"mysite.dd:8083"` without the period and it worked.